# Jquery Mobile Validation error position & selects

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I added bassistance jQuery validation to a form on my jQuery Mobile project. It works perfect, except for the errors show up inside the text inputs and not below them. I know I could use errorPlacement to use divs below my inputs to output my error messages, but this doesn't seem to work for select menus.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is there something I can do different to make the error messages show up below the inputs without using errorPlacement?
2. How can I get error messages to show up for select menus if I have to use errorPlacement?

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $('#page').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
        $('#registrationForm').validate({
            rules: {
                firstname: {
                    required: true
                },
                lastname: {
                    required: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    remote: "duplicateCheck.php"
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                verify_password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                },
                handicap: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 2,
                    digits: true
                },
                stopper: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                firstname: {
                    required: "Please enter your first name."
                },
                lastname: {
                    required: "Please enter your last name."
                },
                email: {
                    required: "Please enter your email.",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email.",
                },
                password: {
                    required: "Please enter a password.",
                    minlength: "You password must be at least 5 characters long."
                },
                verify_password: {
                    required: "Please enter a password.",
                    minlength: "You password must be at least 5 characters long.",
                    equalTo: "You passwords did not match."
                },
                handicap: {
                    required: "Please enter your handicap.",
                    maxlength: "Your max handicap can't be higher than 99.",
                    digits: "Please only enter numbers."
                },
                stopper: {
                    required: "Please enter the word above."
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is my error css:

```
label.error {
    color: red;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait){
    label.error {
        margin-left: 0;
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape){
    label.error {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 22%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more careful when tagging your questions. jQuery Validate and jQuery Validation Engine are two different things.  Edited.

Comment: Sorry for that. Thank you for fixing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, when using jQuery Validate plugin along with jQuery Mobile, the error messages show up below the input element. Removing your custom `errorPlacement` callback function...

**Simple DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/7rXnS/**

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {

    $('#registrationForm').validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: {
                required: "Please enter your first name."
            },
            lastname: {
                required: "Please enter your last name."
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**However**, jQuery Mobile wraps `select` elements within `div` elements so when the plugin adds the error `label` it *appears* to be placed inside of the `select` element.  To fix this, use the `errorPlacement` callback as follows.  It checks to see if the element is a `select` element and then inserts the error `label` *after* the outermost `div` wrapper.  If the element is not a `select`, it just uses the default placement.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if (element.is('select')) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parents('div.ui-select'));
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);  // default placement
    }
}
```

**DEMO using a `select`:  http://jsfiddle.net/QuwkZ/**

Answer (score 0):

Dropping by to mention to that as of Jquery Mobile 1.4.3, this is still and issue and @Sparky's suggested workaround fixes it.